# Are Gift Aid payments deductible from the point of view of Child Tax Credit claims?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-credit

Can I reduce my declared income on my Child Tax Credit claim by my Gift Aided charitable donations made in the tax year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes

As per [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/tax-credits-income-working-sheet-tc825), if you make Gift Aid donations, pension contributions or have a trading loss, these cut your total income figure for tax credits purposes.